# Why does a \hrule need text around it to be drawn?

Tags: rules

Why does a `\hrule` need text around it to work? Example that does *not* draw a line:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
%foo
\hrule
%bar
\end{document}
```

If one removes the `%` before `%foo` or `%bar` (or both) the line is drawn perfectly fine. According to the comments, this is because the rule needs not to be in vertical mode. The command `\hrule` shows a very clear intention: "Dear compiler, please draw a horizontal line!" So, why doesn't `\hrule` leave vertical mode automatically?

Of course, this probably is a pure "academical" problem, because in any real world document one has *some* content. ;)

Comment: I'm assuming it needs to be out of vertical mode?

Comment: Along the line of @daleif's comment, try `\begin{document}
\leavevmode\hrule
\end{document}`

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question accordingly (why doesn't it leave automatically?).

Comment: Consider using `\hrulefill` if you want it to work even in vertical mode.

Comment: @daleif To the contrary: `\hrule` forces vertical mode.

Comment: I knew it had to be one or the other.

Comment: `\rule{\linewidth}{.4pt}` also work in vertical mode.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`\hrule` is a "primitive" instruction. The natural or default width of the rule drawn by this instruction is the width of the vertical box that encloses the `\hrule` instruction (see chap. 21 of the TeXbook, "Making Boxes"). If the width of the enclosing box is zero and if you don't specify an explicit width instead, no horizontal line is generated.

An example of `\hrule` with an explicit width and *no surrounding text* would be:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document} 
\hrule width3cm 
\end{document}
```

The reason why

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document} 
\leavevmode
\hrule
\end{document}
```

generates a line of width `\textwidth` is that `\leavevmode` is defined as follows (see p. 356 of the TeXbook):

```
\def\leavevmode{\unhbox\voidb@x} % begins a paragraph, if necessary
```

where `\voidb@x` (unsurprisingly, given its name) generates a completely empty "box" (in the TeX sense of the word) and `\unhbox` is a TeX primitive that unpacks the contents ot its argument (which must be a "box") and places them in horizontal mode. (Since `\voidb@x` has no contents, `\unhbox` returns nothing. However, it "does nothing" in horizontal mode.) Thus, immediately after `\leavevmode` is finished, TeX is in "horizontal mode". The width of the enclosing vertical box is given by, you guessed it, `\textwidth`; hence, `\hrule` draws a line of width `\textwidth`.

Comment: Another example where `\hrule` adjusts to fit the box size is in the case of leaders.  Compare `\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 1pt \hfill \kern 0pt` to `\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 1pt \hfill \kern 3in`

Answer (score 3):

> Dear TeX, please end the paragraph, if you're typesetting one, and make a rule with the default height (0.4pt) and depth (0pt), as wide as the box where the rule will end up in.

Now, if I compile the following document

```
\documentclass{article}

\showoutput

\begin{document}

\hrule

\end{document}
```

I get the following in the log file:

```
Completed box being shipped out [1]
\vbox(633.0+0.0)x407.0
.\glue 16.0
.\vbox(617.0+0.0)x345.0, shifted 62.0
..\vbox(12.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 12.0fil
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x345.0
..\glue 25.0
..\glue(\lineskip) 0.0
..\vbox(550.0+0.0)x0.0, glue set 539.94232fil
...\write-{}
...\glue(\topskip) 9.6
...\rule(0.4+0.0)x*
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\glue 0.0
...\glue 0.0 plus 0.0001fil
..\glue(\baselineskip) 23.55556
..\hbox(6.44444+0.0)x345.0, glue set 170.0fil
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 1
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
```

The first line after the banner describes the page being shipped out, which has height 633pt (`\textheight` plus the header and the footer), no depth and width 407pt (\textwidth). Then

```
..\vbox(12.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 12.0fil
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x345.0
```

is the (empty) header, followed by 25pt of space (`\headsep`) and `\lineskip` (because the following box is very high).

The following box is the page body

```
..\vbox(550.0+0.0)x0.0, glue set 539.94232fil
```

that has height 550pt (the `\textheight`) and width 0pt, because it contains no box: just a default `\write` that's always added to the first page, the `\topskip`, the rule and fill up glue. What follows, that is,

```
..\glue(\baselineskip) 23.55556
..\hbox(6.44444+0.0)x345.0, glue set 170.0fil
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 1
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
```

is the footer with the page number 1 centered.

The rule is represented by

```
...\rule(0.4+0.0)x*
```

meaning exactly what I described at the beginning: the width is determined by the (vertical) box the rule ends up in.

Note that `\hrule` is a *vertical command*, so it ends the paragraph being typeset; TeX adds no interline glue before and after the rule.

You can try

```
\hbox{aaa}
\hrule
\hbox{bbb}
```

instead, getting

[image]

because the box width is determined by the widest box inside. Since no paragraph is started, the rule ends up with the same width as the bottom `\hbox`.

TeX primitives are very peculiar, aren't they?