# \hrule within \textblock (from textpos package) does not appear in the output

Tags: beamer, rules, textpos

My code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{Demo}

\begin{textblock*}{\textwidth}(20mm,20mm)
\vspace{5mm}\hrule height 1mm\vspace{5mm}
\end{textblock*}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Why does the `\hrule` not appear in the output? How can I fix it?

Comment: Is there any precise reason for using `textblock`?

Comment: @egreg I have multiple frames. Each frame has three pieces of content: (1) code block (2) another code block (3) commentary. I want these three pieces to remain fixed in all the frames and not jump around. I know I can solve this by using `overlayarea` in a single frame but I don't want to do that because these frames contain different ideas, so I want them to be separate frames. Combining them into a single frame does not reflect the notion that they contain different ideas (e.g., the frame number in the footer does not increment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `textblock*` environment uses the properties of the content to determine the size of the box (even though the `textpos` manual states that the width of `textpos*` is absolute). The TeX primitive `\hrule` takes as width the width of the of the vertical box that encloses the `\hrule` instruction (see [Why does a \hrule need text around it to be drawn?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261918/why-does-a-hrule-need-text-around-it-to-be-drawn)), which is empty in this case.

Possible solutions are to use `\leavevmode` (that sets the width of the box to `\textwidth`, see the linked question), or specify the width of the `\hrule` manually, or to use the command `\rule` with a specified width.

MWE below, with some examples of how `textpos*` handles different types of content for illustration purposes (using the `showboxes` package option).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay,showboxes]{textpos}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{Demo}
\color{green}\vspace{5mm}\hrule height 1mm\vspace{5mm}
\begin{textblock*}{\textwidth}(10mm,20mm)
\vspace{2mm}\hrule height 1mm\vspace{2mm}% zero width
\end{textblock*}
\begin{textblock*}{\textwidth}(10mm,30mm)
\vspace{2mm}\leavevmode\hrule height 1mm\vspace{2mm}
\end{textblock*}
\begin{textblock*}{\textwidth}(10mm,40mm)
\color{red}\vspace{2mm}\hrule height 1mm width \textwidth\vspace{2mm}
\end{textblock*}
\begin{textblock*}{\textwidth}(10mm,50mm)
\color{blue}\rule{\textwidth}{1mm}
\end{textblock*}
%further examples of textblock*
\begin{textblock*}{\textwidth}(10mm,60mm)% width of the character
\phantom{X}
\end{textblock*}
\begin{textblock*}{\textwidth}(10mm,70mm)% does not show

\end{textblock*}
\begin{textblock*}{\textwidth}(10mm,80mm)% full width
\color{black}X
\end{textblock*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting. Generally the specified width _is_ the width of the textblock (the height is always the height of the content), but in (slightly odd) cases such as these, where there's no text content, the outer box isn't drawn.  I'm not sure if that's a bug or not (probably is). Your case, @Marijn, where the `\phantom{X}` has a tight box drawn, may be an old version of textpos – I don't see that when I try with v1.9.1. `\leavevmode\vskip{XXXmm}` is probably the best way of getting an empty box, with the outline drawn.

Comment: See https://bitbucket.org/nxg/textpos/issues/12/with-showboxes-empty-content-may-not-show (though I fear I'm going to have to abandon bitbucket before long)